# Finding css for wp-calendar shadow

Tags: html, wordpress, calendar, css

I'm using WP-Calendar for my wordpress site and I have some problems with the WP-Calendar on full Calendar option. There's a strange shadow alongside the title as well as the Title showing up next to the date. First question is for the text shadow. I've tried looking for the right place to change this but i'm out of idea's: I've looked for the class="fc-event-title'and css named title or catagory (because it should be catagory 3) and I've triend adding html to the css file of the template, but this doesn't make a change either... Also no luck with trying to google the answer.

The link is: http://hetiseral.nl/kalender, see the bottom.
Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Greetings, Gea

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `text-shadow:none;` to your class `.fc-event-inner`

Comment: lol, did a lot of css changing that didn't work, this worked, thank you! :)